# Firebase Web import is undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to use [`re-base`](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) to connect to a Firebase app using React.

Here's what my React component looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
const base = new Firebase('https://my-firebase-app.firebaseio.com');

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ref = base.syncState('coffees', {
      context: this,
      asArray: true,
      state: 'coffees',
      then: () => {
        console.log('finished base.syncState')
      }
    });
    ...
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    base.removeBinding(this.ref);
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

My issue is that when my app is built, I'm getting `'n' is undefined` in the Firebase API, near these lines:

```
};function Fa() {
        return Math.floor(2147483648 * Math.random()).toString(36) + Math.abs(Math.floor(2147483648 * Math.random()) ^ ja()).toString(36);
    };var w;a: {
        var Ga = n.navigator;if (Ga) {
            var Ha = Ga.userAgent;if (Ha) {
                w = Ha;break a;
            }
        }w = "";
    };function Ia() {
```

Even if I comment out the `const base='...'` line, the error is still thrown. It leads me to believe that:
A: Something is wrong with the Firebase API file
B: Babel/Webpack is mangling something it shouldn't. However, I've tried setting the Babel loader in webpack to `compact: false`, to no avail.

Finally, here's a look at my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^0.14.7",
  "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
  "react-router": "^2.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
  "eslint": "^2.4.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.2.3",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.10.0",
  "re-base": "^1.5.1",
  "webpack": "^1.12.14",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
}
```

I'm stuck because this causes the entire app to fail loading & I have no idea where to start debugging. Any insight would be amazing!

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/vPztQKZQHC0

Answer (score 0):

My one problem was with my webpack config (that I didn't post).

I am using the `babel-loader` plugin. I had the `exclude` option set to `'/node_modules'`. The solution was to remove the quotes, so the `babel-loader` now looks something like this:

`module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/, // note the absence of ' '
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }`

Setting this value properly fixed my issue.